# Are order-only prerequisites in GNU Makefile available in CMake and if not, what are the alternative options?

Tags: makefile, cmake

In GNU `make`, if a target A depend on two targets B and C, but using target C to build A requires that target B has already been built (target C itself doesn't depend on B however), I can use order-only prerequisites.

Are there any alternatives in `CMake`? I know `CMake` is just a configuration tool so the question may be better rephrased as "Can I write CMakeLists.txt in a way so that it generates Makefiles with order-only prerequisites?"

Alternative solutions are also welcome. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical case of using an order-only prerequisite is to make sure a directory is prepared before it is used in some make rule. Usually, **cmake** takes care of the directories for all the targets that are under it's control. But if you really need some directory, you can use a custom target command like this:

```
add_custom_target(build-time-make-directory ALL
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory ${directory})
```

This target is "with no output" so it will always be built, but the targets that depend on it won't necessarily be rebuilt.

This is not limited to `mkdir`. Here is another example:

```
add_executable(qqexe qq.c)
add_custom_target(_custom_target COMMAND touch pp.c COMMENT pp)
add_dependencies(qqexe _custom_target)
```

Each time you run **make**, the timestamp of **pp.c** will refresh, but the **qqexe** will not be rebuilt unless the timestamp of **qq.c** changes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It helps me understand CMake better. Are there any examples that the other target will not **alway**s be rebuilt? Or maybe you can give an example that I will need to build B first and then build C if I want to build A, but if I only want to build C then B is not necessarily rebuilt even if the source file of B has been updated (since C **itself** is not dependent on B). Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I propose a deal: you post a CMakeLists.txt that does an unnecessary rebuild of some target, and I'll show you how this script can be fixed.