# How to express order-only dependencies in CMake?

Tags: c++, makefile, build, cmake

I work on a project where we use a code generation library in C++ to produce object files during our build.

Here's the setup:

1. We wish to generate routines `A`, `B`, etc.
2. We have a directory containing source files like `A.gen.cpp`, `B.gen.cpp`, etc. These are compiled to corresponding `A.gen.o`, `B.gen.o`, etc.
3. These are linked together with external dependencies to create an executable `unity_generator`.
4. We run `unity_generator` once for each of `A`, `B`, etc. to produce `A.o`, `A.h`, `B.o`, `B.h`, etc.
5. We link `A.o`, `B.o`, etc. along with its **own, separate** set of external dependencies into a static or dynamic library. We also produce a single header that includes `A.h`, `B.h`, etc.

Steps 2 and 3 are straightforward. We link them all into a single executable in step 3 because relinking the external dependencies into separate executables takes an unacceptably long time.

In Make, we express this by having `A.o` depend on `A.gen.cpp` and list `unity_generator` as an order-only prerequisite. This allows us to only rerun `unity_generator` for the final `*.o` files that actually need updating, rather than regenerating all of them when any `*.gen.cpp` file is updated.

The final dependency graph looks like this, where dotted lines represent order-only dependencies.

> [image]

How can we accomplish this in CMake?

Comment: I believe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47753129/192373) provides enough info to resolve your request. If it doesn't cover your use case, feel free to ask for more.